# Swift: How to return Class<UITableViewDataSource>?

Tags: ios, swift

How to define the protocol in Swift :(

```
@protocol Protocol <NSObject>

- (Class<UITableViewDataSource>)generateObject;

@end
```

**Edit**: If I want to define a function in OC like this:

```
- (UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource>)generateObject;
```

The swift style like the following, right?

```
func generateObject() -> UITableViewDataSource
```

I think this way ignores some type checking... Is there a better way to do this in swift?

Answer (score 0):

```
func generateObject() -> UITableViewDataSource
```

Answer (score 0):

It should rather look like this in swift,

```
protocol Protocol: NSObjectProtocol {
    func generateObject() -> UITableViewDataSource
}
```

Comment: The return value is an instance not a class?

Comment: That is what the return type means. You cannot return protocol or instantiate a protocol by any means. It just means that you will be returning a class which conforms to UITableViewDataSource protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protocol Protocol: NSObjectProtocol {
    func generateObject() -> UITableViewDataSource.Type
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You define protocols in a very similar way to classes, structures, and enumerations:

```
protocol Protocol: NSObjectProtocol 
{
    func generateObject() -> UITableViewDataSource
}
```

For more please refer official [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)